# iOS: Limit local notifications to a certain time frame?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, uilocalnotification, nsdatecomponents

I am working on an app that uses local notifications, which are repeating in an interval chosen by the user (between 5 and 60 minutes).

I would like to enable users to also choose a certain time frame so that the app will fire notifications only during this time frame. I was thinking about using NSDate and some kind of conditional statement where the notification only fires if the current time is in the time frame which was chosen by the user.

Do you think that will work or am I overseeing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` for this.

> Triggers a notification at the specified date and time.

See
[official documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/uncalendarnotificationtrigger)

Calendar triggers can also be repeating, so it should serve your purpose.

Comment: I think this won't serve my purpose because it triggers only at one specified time, right? However, I want users to be able to choose a) how often they want to get a notification (e.g. "Every 20 minutes") and b) in which time frame they want to get it (e.g. "Between 9.00 and 12.00 AM") so that for this example, the user will be notified every 20 minutes between 9 and 12 am.

Comment: As I've said, UNCalendarNotificationTrigger can be repeating, so for your example, you can set up triggers for every 20 minutes between 9 and 12AM and repeat each of them daily or you can set up just one, which is repeated every 20 minutes and then you cancel it when it reaches 12AM.

Comment: Ok thanks. I am still unsure on how to combine both features though. If I set up UNCalendarNotificationTrigger like this `let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger.init(dateMatching: date, repeats: true)` it will simply fire at that specific time and not repeat e.g. every 20 minutes after that right? But simply adding a `TimeInterval` wouldn't do it, I guess?

Comment: It depends on what date is. If you look at the official documentation that I have linked, it tells you what date can be and how it repeats.
Where do you want to add a TimeInterval and what for?

Comment: Well, I need some code so that it repeats the notification during the chosen time interval ("every 20 minutes"). At the moment I am using UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger for that. What if I did it using a while loop like this? `while chosenHourStart >= date.hour || chosenHourEnd <= date.hour {
    //will add the code for UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger here
}`"chosenHourStart" and "chosenHourEnd" would then be the variables chosen by the user.

Comment: I just realized that it needs to be an if statement then. `if chosenHourStart >= date.hour || chosenHourEnd <= date.hour { //will add the code for UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger here }` Do you think that could work or is there a more convenient way using UNCalendarNotificationTrigger?